# How to programmatically scale up app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I have an application which uses app engine auto scaling. It usually runs 0 instances, except if some authorised users use it.

This application need to run automated voice calls as fast as possible on thousands of people with keypad interactions (no, it's not spam, it's [redcall](https://github.com/redcall-io/app)!).

Programmatically speaking, we ask Twilio to initialise calls through its Voice API 5 times/sec and it basically works through webhooks, at least 2, but most of the time 4 hits per call. So GAE need to scale up very quickly and some requests get lost (which is just a hang up on the user side) at the beginning of the trigger, when only one instance is ready.

I would like to know if it is possible to programmatically scale up App Engine (through [an API?](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/getting-started)) before running such triggers in order to be ready when the storm will blast?

Comment: This is not an answer, but have you reviewed the architecture for App Engine? Is this even the right service where very fast scaling is required? Is this the right service for thousands of concurrent consumers? Review this document for setting the `minInstances`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/setting-autoscaling-params-in-explorer and this one on scaling https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: @JohnHanley, one of the features of GAE standard is that it is able to scale up to a lot of instances very quickly.  I have seen it quickly scale from 2 instances to 50 instances to handle traffic spikes without a glitch.

Comment: @gaefan - Agreed. But quickly scaling does not mean "right now". Also based upon details in the question, I recommend that he review his architecture and design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was to delegate sending the communication through Cloud Tasks:

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks

https://github.com/redcall-io/app/blob/master/symfony/src/Communication/Processor/QueueProcessor.php

Tasks can try again hitting the app engine in case of errors, and make the app engine pop new instances when the surge comes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to give [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/configuring-warmup-requests) a try. As they load your app's code into a new instance before any live requests reach that instance. Thus reducing the time it takes to answer while you GAE instance has scaled down to zero.

The link I have shared with you, includes the PHP7 runtime as I see you are familiar with it.

I would also like to agree with John Hanley, since finding a sweet spot on how many idle instances you have available, would also help the performance of your app.